# Getting illegal variable name/number error when inserting using OracleCommand

Tags: c#, .net, oracleclient, oraclecommand

When I try to insert a record into a table using C#, I am getting the following error,

```
Message = "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number\n"
Source = "System.Data.OracleClient"
StackTrace = "   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)\r\n   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameterBinding.Bind(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, NativeBuffer parameterBuffer, OracleConnection connection, Bo...
TargetSite = {Void CheckError(System.Data.OracleClient.OciErrorHandle, Int32)}
```

My code:

```
Int32 intLogID = 0;
strSQL = "INSERT INTO log_data(log_id, response_msg) "
                                        + "VALUES(?, ?)";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strSQL, conn);
cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("log_id", OracleType.Int32).Value = intLogID;
cmd.Parameters.Add("response_msg", OracleType.VarChar, 256).Value = strResMsg;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My table structure:

```
LOG_ID          NOT NULL NUMBER(18) 
RESPONSE_MSG    VARCHAR2(256)
```

I am able to successfully insert into the table When I tried it manually using,

```
INSERT INTO log_data(log_id, response_msg)
values (1067365, 'test');
```

I even tried `int intLogID = 0;` and `cmd.Parameters.Add("log_id", OracleType.Number).Value = intLogID;`

Also `Int32` with Number binding combination and `int` with `Int32` binding combinations.

But still getting same error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have your query as

```
"INSERT INTO log_data(log_id, response_msg) VALUES(:log_id,:response_msg)"
```

Coz you are supplying those specific parameters like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("log_id", OracleType.Number).Value = intLogID;
```